# Reactive/Calculate Columns in rhandsontable in shiny- rstudio

Tags: shiny, rstudio, rhandsontable

I am trying to add a custom validation to the following interactive table. What I am trying to do is as follows. The table contains three variables namely mpg,cyl and disp. Suppose I edit the mpg value of the first row. Then once I press the enter button, disp value of the 1st row should be automatically changed calculated as disp=mpg/cyl. Here mpg value being the new value I edited. Likewise if I edit cyl in a particular row again disp of that particular row should be changed automatically evaluated as disp=mpg/cyl. Moreover if I change disp value of a particular row, cyl of that particular row should be changed automatically calculated as mpg/cyl. I am trying to figure it out a way of doing this.

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui=fluidPage(

rHandsontableOutput("table1")

)

server=function(input, output, session) {

mt=reactive({

datacopy= mtcars[, names(mtcars) %in% c("mpg" , "cyl" , "disp")]
datacopy=data.table(datacopy)
})  


output$table1=renderRHandsontable({

rhandsontable(mt())



})


}



shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this  would achieve what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)

ui=fluidPage(

  rHandsontableOutput("table1")

)

server=function(input, output, session) {

  mt=reactive({

    datacopy <- NULL

    #For initial data upload
    if(is.null(input$table1)){
      datacopy= mtcars[, names(mtcars) %in% c("mpg" , "cyl" , "disp")]
      datacopy=data.table(datacopy) 

    }else{
      datacopy = hot_to_r(input$table1)

      #If there is change in data
      if(!is.null(input$table1$changes$changes)){

        row.no <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[1]
        col.no <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[2]
        new.val <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[4]
        #If the changed value is mpg or cyl
        if(col.no == 0 || col.no == 1){
          datacopy[(row.no+1), 3] = datacopy[(row.no+1), 1]/datacopy[(row.no+1), 2]
        }else{
          datacopy[(row.no+1), 2] = datacopy[(row.no+1), 1]/datacopy[(row.no+1), 3]
        }

      }

    }

    datacopy

  })  


  output$table1=renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(mt())

  })

}



shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope it helps!

**[EDIT]:**
As per your edited answer I have modified the code below. Hopefully this helps.

```
 library(shiny)
    library(datasets)
    library(rhandsontable)
    library(data.table)



    c1= c(rep("0112",3), rep("0113",3),rep("0114",3))
    c2= c( rep(c("A", "B","C"),3))
    c3= c(rep(c("5312", "5421", "5510"),3)) 
    c4=c(rep(c("Area", "Yield", "Prod"),3))
    c5 = c( rep(2010,9))
    c6= c( 4,68,16169,1062,1.5,43225,800,1.25,100)
    data_=cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6)
    data_=as.data.frame(data_)
    names(data_) = c("CPCCode", "Item","ElementCode","El","Year","Value")
    data_$Value=as.numeric(levels( data_$Value))[ data_$Value]
    data_$Year= as.integer(levels( data_$Year))[data_$Year]
    data_$ElementCode = as.character(data_$ElementCode)
    rownames(data_) = NULL


    ui=fluidPage(

      rHandsontableOutput("table1")

    )

    server=function(input, output, session) {

      mt=reactive({

        datacopy <- NULL

        #For initial data upload
        if(is.null(input$table1)){ 

          datacopy <- data_

        }else{
          datacopy = hot_to_r(input$table1)

          #If there is change in data
          if(!is.null(input$table1$changes$changes)){

            row.no <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[1]
            element = datacopy[(row.no + 1), "ElementCode"]
            year= datacopy[(row.no + 1), "Year"]
            cpccode= datacopy[(row.no + 1), "CPCCode"]
            col.no <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[2]
            if(element == "5421"){#Yield

              datacopy$Value[datacopy$CPCCode == cpccode & datacopy$Year == year &  
                               datacopy$ElementCode == "5510"] =
                datacopy$Value[datacopy$CPCCode == cpccode & datacopy$Year == year & 
                                 datacopy$ElementCode == "5312"] *
                datacopy$Value[datacopy$CPCCode == cpccode & datacopy$Year == year & 
                                 datacopy$ElementCode == "5421"]

            }else if(element == "5510"){#Area

              datacopy$Value[datacopy$CPCCode == cpccode & datacopy$Year == year & 
                               datacopy$ElementCode == "5312"] = 
                datacopy$Value[datacopy$CPCCode == cpccode & datacopy$Year == year &  
                                 datacopy$ElementCode == "5510"] /
                datacopy$Value[datacopy$CPCCode == cpccode & datacopy$Year == year & 
                                 datacopy$ElementCode == "5421"]

            }

          }

        }

        datacopy

      }) 

      output$table1=renderRHandsontable({

        rhandsontable(mt())

      })

    }



    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped a lot. I didn't know about changes option. I am wondering what input$table1$changes$changes gives you.

Comment: `input$table1$changes$changes`is a list containing the changes done in the `rhandsontable` by the user. `unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)` gives you a vector whose first and second element is the row number(0 indexed)  and column number (0 indexed) respectively of the cell whose value was altered, the third element is the previous value in the cell and fourth element is the new value in the cell.

Comment: Oh. This is very useful for what I am developing. I have no words to thank you. Cheers!! great stuff.

Comment: Another question : what this if(col.no == 0 || col.no == 1) mean? and why you write (row.no+1) ?

Comment: `col.no == 0` refers to the first column of your dataset(mpg) and,`col.no == 1` refers to second column of your dataset(cyl). So based on the condition given in your question we have to calculate the new values. `row.no+1` because the value you get is zero-indexed while R is one-indexed. Hope this clears your doubt!

Comment: Thank you. I have the same problem but with a different data set. I tried to do your suggestion and it does not work. Here is my code                                   #####

Comment: I do not have access to post the new code here. If you send me an email address I can send you the code. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you edit this question or post a new question for the new code, that way it would be helpful for others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: I edited the code. I have no access to post new questions either. I hope you can see the edtion now! thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can see it. It is removed by the system.  I am posting it from my brother's account please do check. It is Malinda Samaratunga

Comment: I did edit the answer to accommodate your dataset and the changes you wanted. See my edited answer.

Comment: sorry I did not see the edited version. Now I check and let you know

Comment: I am wondering if there is search box for rhandsontable as in data table output.