# Reactive/Calculate column in Rhandsontable where source data is dataframe from reactive value

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a shiny app that will display a rhandsontable depending on the Product Category that the user wants to review. I need to recalculate one of the columns if  the user inputs different values into another column and I found this example to be useful:
[Reactive/Calculate Columns in rhandsontable in shiny- rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074184/reactive-calculate-columns-in-rhandsontable-in-shiny-rstudio)
except that I get the data of my tables from a reactive object so when I redirect "datacopy" to the function to get the data, this code does not work. Could anyone please help me achieve it?
Here is a sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(data.table)

ui=fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("table1")
)

server=function(input, output, session) {

 mt=reactive({
 datacopy <- NULL
 #For initial data upload
 if(is.null(input$table1)){
     datacopy= mtcars[, names(mtcars) %in% c("mpg" , "cyl" , "disp")]
     datacopy=data.table(datacopy) 
 }else{
  datacopy = hot_to_r(input$table1)
  #If there is change in data
  if(!is.null(input$table1$changes$changes)){
    row.no <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[1]
    col.no <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[2]
    new.val <- unlist(input$table1$changes$changes)[4]
    #If the changed value is mpg or cyl
    if(col.no == 0 || col.no == 1){
      datacopy[(row.no+1), 3] = datacopy[(row.no+1), 1]*datacopy[(row.no+1), 2]
    }else{
      datacopy[(row.no+1), 2] = datacopy[(row.no+1), 1]*datacopy[(row.no+1), 3]
    }
  }
}
datacopy
  })  

output$table1=renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(mt())
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```