# How to make rhandsontable re-render automatically after selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm working on a Shiny app in which a user can input some data into different data sets, which is then used to calculate other variables in the data set. The choice of a data set is determined by a selecInput.
I chose an rHandsontable because it successfully mimics the familiar spreadsheet input. I adapted the solution for the calculation of the columns from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074184/reactive-calculate-columns-in-rhandsontable-in-shiny-rstudio) and things work quite well. except for one little thing: after the selection of a different data set, the rhandsontable is not re-rendered until the user interacts with it. I understand this is what should happen, but in my case we need re-rendering.
I have tried different combinations of observe, observreEvent, and eventReactive, nothing worked. The closest I came with the inclusion of the reactiveVal indicator of the selection change, which at least signals that the new data should be used.
Here is the MRE of where I got.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data <- list (
  table1 = data.frame( beginning = as.numeric(rep(8, 4)),
                ending = as.numeric(rep(15, 4))),

table2 = data.frame( beginning = as.numeric(rep(9, 4)),
                ending = as.numeric(rep(17, 4)))
)

data[["table1"]]$hours <- data[["table1"]]$ending - data[["table1"]]$beginning
data[["table2"]]$hours <- data[["table2"]]$ending - data[["table2"]]$beginning

############################# UI #############################

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("tab", "Chose table: ", choices = list("table1", "table2")),
  fluidRow(wellPanel(
    column(6,
           rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
           actionButton(inputId="enter",label="Save")
    ),

    column(6,
           textOutput("title"),
           tableOutput("tabela")
    )))
))

########################## SEREVER ###########################

server=function(input,output, session){

  tab_change <- reactiveVal(FALSE)


   # rw <- reactivePoll(1000, session, file_name, read.csv2)
   react_week <- reactive({
     df <- data[[input$tab]]
     })

  output$title <- renderText(input$tab)

  output$tabela <- renderTable(react_week())

  observeEvent(input$tab,
               {tab_change(TRUE)
               })


  # Calculation of columns
  for_week <- reactive({

    datacopy <- NULL

    #For initial data upltabd
    if(isolate(tab_change()) || is.null(input$hot)) {
      datacopy <- react_week()
    }
    else {
      datacopy <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    }

    #If there is change in data
    if(!is.null(input$hot$changes$changes)){

      col.no <- as.numeric(unlist(input$hot$changes$changes)[2])
      new.val <- unlist(input$hot$changes$changes)[4]

      #If the changed value is prihod or odhod
      if(col.no == 0 || col.no == 1){
        datacopy[, 3] <- as.numeric(datacopy[, 2]) - as.numeric(datacopy[, 1])
      }

    }

    tab_change(FALSE)
    datacopy

  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(for_week())
  )

  observeEvent(input$enter, {
    data[[input$tab]] <<- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    output$tabela <- renderTable( data[[input$tab]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm new to Shiny, so I may be missing the obvious, but is there a way to re-render the rhandsontable immediately after the selection change short of using some low level functions like sendInputMessage which I dread?
And if there isn't, where can I find some instructions of how to construct such a message to work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eventReactive` and trigger by `input$tab` and `input$hot` rather than `reactive` for your `for_week` reactive object:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data <- list (
  table1 = data.frame( beginning = as.numeric(rep(8, 4)),
                       ending = as.numeric(rep(15, 4))),

  table2 = data.frame( beginning = as.numeric(rep(9, 4)),
                       ending = as.numeric(rep(17, 4)))
)

data[["table1"]]$hours <- data[["table1"]]$ending - data[["table1"]]$beginning
data[["table2"]]$hours <- data[["table2"]]$ending - data[["table2"]]$beginning

############################# UI #############################

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("tab", "Chose table: ", choices = list("table1", "table2")),
  fluidRow(wellPanel(
    column(6,
           rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
           actionButton(inputId="enter",label="Save")
    ),

    column(6,
           textOutput("title"),
           tableOutput("tabela")
    )))
))

########################## SEREVER ###########################

server=function(input,output, session){

  tab_change <- reactiveVal(FALSE)


  # rw <- reactivePoll(1000, session, file_name, read.csv2)
  react_week <- reactive({
    df <- data[[input$tab]]
  })

  output$title <- renderText(input$tab)

  output$tabela <- renderTable(react_week())

  observeEvent(input$tab,
               {tab_change(TRUE)
               })


  # Calculation of columns
  # ----------------------------Modified here----------------------------
  # for_week <- reactive({
  for_week <- eventReactive(c(input$tab, input$hot), {
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    datacopy <- NULL

    #For initial data upltabd
    if(isolate(tab_change()) || is.null(input$hot)) {
      datacopy <- react_week()
    }
    else {
      datacopy <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    }

    #If there is change in data
    if(!is.null(input$hot$changes$changes)){

      col.no <- as.numeric(unlist(input$hot$changes$changes)[2])
      new.val <- unlist(input$hot$changes$changes)[4]

      #If the changed value is prihod or odhod
      if(col.no == 0 || col.no == 1){
        datacopy[, 3] <- as.numeric(datacopy[, 2]) - as.numeric(datacopy[, 1])
      }

    }

    tab_change(FALSE)
    datacopy

  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(for_week())
  )

  observeEvent(input$enter, {
    data[[input$tab]] <<- hot_to_r(input$hot)
    output$tabela <- renderTable( data[[input$tab]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jim. I tried this again (I now remember trying this earlier), but this breaks the calculation. It seems that I will have to find yet another event, which will activate for_week for the calculation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Code works as far as the refreshing is concerned, but no longer does the calculations. When first two columns are edited, the third column should display their difference. This worked before, with your solution it doesn't work any more.

Comment: I added the input$hot$changes$changes dependency to for_week. Now it works fine. Can you edit your answer with this, since it's you who got me on the right track, so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I added another event `input$hot` and it seems to work fine.